How do I change network name of Windows 11 PC?
My Windows 11 PC came with a generic name DESKTOP-CLIQGVS. I followed the standard name change procedure and changed the name to lifebook. It shows both names now, and it is still visible on the network as DESKTOP-CLIQGVS. Is there a way to get rid of the old name?


Did you restart as the dialog requests?

@DavidPostill Yes, I had and there was no effect. Just a moment ago, I set a static IP address and that caused the name change after reboot. Go figure.

You need to reboot your machine, and then the change will be applied and visible.
